# how does jquery extend() with multiple objects work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, merge, extend

I am trying to modify a plugin and am pulling my hair out trying to understand how extend() is working...

If I have this:

```
$.extend( plugin.ext.oStdClasses, {
      "some":"one"
       },
$.extend( plugin.ext.oStdClasses, plugin.ext.xtraClasses, {
      "some":"two"
       }
```

can someone explain to me what is happening?

Also I want to extend this with my own logic like so:

```
$.extend( plugin.ext.xtraClasses, plugin.ext.moreClasses, {
      "some":"thing",
      "else":"too"
       }
```

However this seems to give me back an empty object. Is it possible to extend the standard classes with the xtra classes with the more classes and overwrite the previous classes?

Thanks for some pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) it states that the first argument for `extend` will be the object modified, so you're best doing something like this:

```
var opts = {};
$.extend(opts, plugin.ext.xtraClasses, plugin.ext.moreClasses, { 
   some: "thing",
   else: "too"
});
console.log(opts);
```

Comment: so opts would be my basic classes to which xtra and more will be added?

Answer (score 2):

$.extend extending first passed argumnet.

for example:

```
var first = {first: true};
var second = {second: true}

$.extend(first, second);

console.log(first); // output {first: true, second: true}
console.log(second); // output {second: true}

var third = $.extend({}, first, second, {third: true});
console.log(third); // output {first: true, second: true, third: true}
```

Comment: what happens if I omit the {} in var third?

Comment: the same as in the first case(first object extended too)

Comment: that's where my pulled out here is... ;-)